# Redirect REST-Call to other REST-Service in Dotnet

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I want to build a gateway service to seperate my UI from my backend-services.

**Example:**

- UI calls `GET www.myGateway.com/resourceService/someResource/id`
- Gateway redirects to `GET www.myBackendResourceService.com/someResource/id`
- Errors like 404 etc. or the response should be routed back to the UI.

Is there a best practise to receive a http-call and redirect it to another webservice?
I could build a generic controller which determines which url to call and perform a get with a httpClient and rethrow exceptions or return the content always as string, but this feels wrong.

How should this be done?

```
[HttpGet($"{serviceName}/{parameter1}/{parameter2}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> GetSomething(
    string serviceName,
    string parameter1,
    string parameter2,
    CancellationToken ct = default)
{
    string urlBackend = GetUrlBackend(serviceName);

    var response = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(new Uri(new Uri(urlBackend ), string.Join("/", parameters)));

    // Do some ErrorHandling..

    return response.Content.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/multi-container-microservice-net-applications/implement-api-gateways-with-ocelot. Don't reinvent the wheel.